# How to notify user that an HTML5 offline web app needs updating?

Tags: html, offline, notify

I am creating an HTML5 offline web app for use on iOS and Android.

Is there a mechanism for notifying the user that an update is available - e.g., a red dot on the application's shortcut icon? If there isn't, would I be able to achieve this maybe with push notifications or some other way?

I understand that I can use the manifest file to declare which files the app should attempt to update from the server - but my client is asking if the app would be able to visually notify to the user of the need to update.

Comment: I donot understand how the app would communicate with the server without a connection to server!

Answer (score 1):

No, None of the app's code will run unless you launch the app, at which point it will automatically update based on the manifest if you are online. If you are off line then there is no way for the app to check if it needs to be updated.